# Getting javascript debugging working in VS2010 web developer express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have downloaded the VS2010 Web Devleoper Express to learn MVC3.

I have created  a javascript file and added it to my page and tried to set a breakpoint on it for debugging in VS.

I have the web.config setting and project properties setting set but debugging does not work.

I have googled and called MS support but cant get an answer.

Would you have any ideas or lead me to an answer.

And no I do not want to use Firebug I want to use VS becuase it should work.

Malcolm

Answer (score 1):

Posted by Microsoft on 28/07/2011 at 16:00

Thanks for your feedback. Currently JS breakpoint mapping to source files in MVC is not supported, and is out of scope for our next release. However we are investigating possible solutions for future release

See: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/652428/mvc-3-mvc-2-debug-ignores-javascript-breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not enabled script debugging in IE. Follow the instructions in this [**article**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2007/03/09/jscript-debugging-in-visual-web-developer-orcas.aspx) exactly.

Comment: @Malcolm Check this msdn [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7seh8d72.aspx) for visual studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

One way you can make sure you will hit the break point is to use debugger(); method.
for e.g.

function foo()
{
debugger();
///Stuff
}

This will force your visual studio (weather your Studio is in debug mode or not) to give you option to go into debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

How are you starting to debug? E.g. are you pressing F5?

If you are, make sure you have set your start page (Right-Click file, Set As Start Page) to the page you want to debug.

Is the BP hollow or solid red?